# ¿Cómo redireccionar a una vista de angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript

He comenzado a desarrollar con **`Angular 2`** en un proyecto que está en la *versión 2.0.0-rc.6*, y he estado tratando de resolver un error con respecto a las rutas del aplicativo, pero sinceramente ya no sé qué hacer.

El problema es el siguiente: Creé un servicio para gestionar todo lo que tiene que ver con las peticiones *http*, que yo realizo a una API, en dicho servicio tengo un método que se encarga de tratar errores comunes que puedan arrojar las peticiones, el problema llega cuando se ejecuta un condicional evaluando el código de respuesta de la petición *http* `(error.status === 401)` , lo que quiero lograr con esto es que cuando se ejecute el condicional, redireccionar al usuario a la vista del *login*, por tanto uso lo siguiente `this.router.navigate([’/login’]);` pero en la consola del navegador me arroja el siguiente error: **cannot read property ‘navigate’ of undefined.**

Error de la consola del Chrome.

> **>** EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
>
> **>** ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>
> **>** TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
>
> at CatchSubscriber.HttpToolsService.HandleErrors [as selector] (*http-tools.service.ts:157*)
>
> at CatchSubscriber.error (*catch.js:52*)
>
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (*Subscriber.js:128*)
>
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (*Subscriber.js:102*)
>
> at Observable.subscribe (*angular2-jwt.ts:135*)
>
> at Observable.subscribe (*Observable.js:114*)
>
> at MapOperator.call (*map.js:54*)
>
> at Observable.subscribe (*Observable.js:53*)
>
> at Observable._subscribe (*Observable.js:114*)
>
> **>** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 3):

El log indica claramente que no puede hallar la propiedad `navigate` de una variable indefinida que vendría ser `this.router`

Para que ello no suceda recuerda que debes importar router de Angular 2 en tu componente:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
```

Además de agregarlo a tu constructor:

```
constructor(private router:Router){}
```

Esto permitirá que la función `navigate` si tenga una referencia válida.

---

**PD:** Recuerda también que desde Angular 2.0.0-RC.5 la definición de tus routes es sin / por lo que el de login sería algo como esto:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [UnauthenticatedGuard]}
```

Y la forma de navegar a él:

```
this.router.navigate(['login']);
```

Comment: Hola de antemano gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente estoy haciendo todo lo que mencionas y ya tengo importado el router y lo agregué en el constructor, además verifique la ruta y es la siguiente `{ path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent }`, lo único que no sabía era que ya no navegaba con / antepuesto en la ruta, ya he corregido eso, pero el problema persiste, y me llamo la atención que mencionaste componente y yo estoy usando un servicio; ¿abra algún problema con eso ?.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera de hacer eso es con **CanActivate**, de esta manera rediriges sí el usuario no esta autenticado, aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Y lo invocas en cada **router** (routing.ts) así:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Example'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'example-component',
        component: ExampleComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Example'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Lo que haces es buscar si tiene un token activo, en caso de que no sea válido, se le redirige al login y es importante que esto lo hagas en **cada router** excepto en el **login**, si no se va a ciclar infinitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Respecto al problema encontre que debes fijarte en las comillas, el tipo de comillas implica en si funciona o no !

import {Router} from '@angular/router';

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
this.router.navigate([’/usuarios’]);
```

para redireccionar a usuarios funciona bien, para login no !!!